# Why food is still tasty?

Tags: evolution

I'm not a biologist, but it seems that plants with disgusting taste have evolutionary advantage to tasty plants. Same about animals.

There are some species that can not be eaten by man (sharks have poisonous meat). Being eaten by a human — is one of major threats for a shrimp. Does it mean that shrimps are going to become less and less tasty (for a human taste)?

Comment: Why do you think sharks are poison ?

Comment: mercury accumulates in top level predators

Comment: @blacksmith37 "Unprocessed shark meat may have a strong odor of ammonia, due to the high urea content that develops as the fish decomposes". You can eat it, but it's unhealthy. In most countries only shark fins are used as food — other parts are concidered waste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things are not fundamentally tasty or disgusting. A dung fly loves that taste of dungs while I personally prefer the taste of an apple and my dog prefers the taste of duck fat. A classic example is the [gene family TAS2R and the evolution of bitter taste in rodents and primates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitter_taste_evolution).

Predator (incl. herbivores) evolves as to like the taste of what he should be eating ([Carlsson et al., 2009](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1890/080093/full)). Preys (incl. plants) can eventually play out with their taste though, trying to either taste bad to avoid specific predators or taste good to attract specific predators that may disseminate their seeds. I have failed to find evidence that plants can deceive animals at being more tasty than nourishing but you might still want to have a look at [Dethier (1980)](http://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/abs/10.1086/283545), [Sorensen (1983)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00378226) and [Goff and Klee (2006)](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/311/5762/815).

One could therefore expect an evolutionary race (red queen) between preys and predators upon how they taste. It would likely be a rather complex race as most species have several predators and several species they prey upon. However, such race on taste would work only if plants can deceive animals which I failed to find evidence for. Arms race for toxic compounds relating to evolution of taste in animals are very much known though ([Edger et al., 2015](http://www.pnas.org/content/112/27/8362.short)).

Comment: So is it a Red queen taste version?

Comment: Yes. But see edit where I made sure to be a bit more safe in not claiming more than it is known. I also added a few references.

Comment: Well, my dog likes long-dead deer bones, and eats horse droppings and hoof parings, among other things I don't think I'd find at all tasty.  OTOH, my horse likes to snack on bitterbrush (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purshia_tridentata ), and eats a lot more hay than I'd care too.  Tastes differ :-)

Comment: Right now mankind is a major predator for a lot of species (shrimps for example) — does it mean that in future generations shrimps will evolve to be less attractive for people?

Comment: @StanislavGoldenshluger More than half of the world production in shrimps are farmed ([according to WWF](https://www.worldwildlife.org/industries/farmed-shrimp)), so it is not really a good example.